# Read/Unread status for emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

i've recently purchased the microsoft365 plan to use it in our company's office. I've setup 6 email accounts on 10 computers (Microsoft Outlook 2016), that means that some of the computers have the same email account (Exchange) installed.

The problem that we have, is that every time someone reads or deletes an email, the same happens on the other computers that use the same email account.

Is there a way to stop Microsoft Outlook from synchronising the status of each email?

Comment: Searching the Internet for "microsoft outlook 2016 make mailbox read only" (no quotes) yields several possible answers that may or may not be helpful.

Comment: As @barrycarter says this could of been resolved with a simple google or MSO forum search. This site to help people when they have exhausted the normal options, not to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, the only way to maintain per-user read/unread mail status is to use Public Folders. No other ways exist, including shared mailboxes.